# Value Error when render used (django 1.7.1)

Tags: django, django-views

I've an error

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/user/accounter/apps/accounter/views.py" in unit_view
  24.     return render(request, 'accounter/unit.html', context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  48.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs),
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  177.     with context_instance.push(dictionary):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/context.py" in push
  54.         return ContextDict(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/context.py" in __init__
  19.         super(ContextDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

Exception Type: ValueError at /accounter/1/
Exception Value: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required
```

Also my view source code:

```
class ProductListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Product

    def get_queryset(self):
            return Product.objects.all()

def unit_view(request, product_id):
    context = Context({
        'product': Product.objects.get(pk=product_id).name,
        'ship_units': ShipUnit.objects.filter(product = product_id),
        'shop_units': ShopUnit.objects.filter(product = product_id),
    })
    return render(request, 'accounter/unit.html', context)
```

I can't figure out what the problem. I've read documentation about using of render and context, also all the examples. But cant find where is my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`render` is a shortcut; it doesn't take a Context object, it takes a plain dict.

```
context = {
    'product': Product.objects.get(pk=product_id).name,
    'ship_units': ShipUnit.objects.filter(product = product_id),
    'shop_units': ShopUnit.objects.filter(product = product_id),
}
```